# How do I give a user access to only the notes he created in mongoDB?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I created a notepad backend project that takes in users and different notes. How do I give the created note an identification that shows that it's a specific user that created it? so when I'm getting each user data it only shows the notes they created.
I tried doing this, but it gives an error.

```
router.post("/newNote", verifyAndAuthorize, async (req, res) => {
req.body._id = req.user.id
const createNote = new note(req.body);
try {
    const savedNote = await createNote.save();
    res.status(200).json(savedNote);
} catch (err) {
    res.status(500).json(err);
}
```

});

I tried changing the ID of the note to equal the ID of the current user, but it gives this error below

```
{
"index": 0,
"code": 11000,
"keyPattern": {
    "_id": 1
},
"keyValue": {
    "_id": "626fc672e5c1932655233192"
}
```

}

Comment: I think I have figured it out. I created a property in the note model called user_Id and I equaled it to the current user ID in the note get router.   it works, but is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your note schema to have the user as a reference field like

```
const noteSchema = Schema({
  _id: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
  author: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: '<user_model_name>' }]
});
```

Hope this helps!

**EDIT:**

`req.body._id = req.user.id` should be changed to `req.body['author'] = req.user.id` because mongoose automatically creates the `_id` field on insert. You are trying to give the `note` record the `_id` field which is not possible.